# What to add to the code so not breaking when XML fields do not exist

Tags: c#, xml

I am parsing an XML file in C#, how I can make sure the code is not breaking if XML does not have one of these fields I am parsing? I don't want to through an exception as well.

```
       StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        var xDocument = XDocument.Load(filePath);
        string xml = xDocument.ToString();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        var col = doc.Root.Elements("LineItems")
                     .Elements("LineItem")
                     .Elements("OrderLine")
                     .Select(e => new
                     {
                         PurchaseOrderNumber = doc.Root.Element("Header").Element("OrderHeader").Element("Purchase").Value,
                         InternalOrderNumber = doc.Root.Element("Header").Element("OrderHeader").Element("InternalOrderNumber").Value,
                         VendorPartNumber = e.Element("VendorPartNumber").Value,
                         ItemStatus = e.Element("ItemStatus").Value,
                         Date = e.Element("ExpectedDate").Value
                     });
```

For example, I removed **ExpectedDate** from XML and this is breaking. what can I add to this code that is not breaking when XML fields do not exist?

I added this and it works:
ate = e.Element("ExpectedDate")?.Value,

But now if ExpectedDate is not existed this would be 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM - How I can have an empty string so this line won't break:

```
  OrderLine orderline = new OrderLine() { ItemStatus = item.ItemStatus, VendorPartNumber = item.VendorPartNumber, Date = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date) };
```

This is XML sample:

```
<Purchase>
    <Header>
    <OrderHeader>
        <TradingId>OPIE</TradingId>
    </OrderHeader>
</Header>
<LineItems>
    <LineItem>
        <OrderLine>
            <UnitPrice>1073.25</UnitPrice>
            <ExtendedLineAmount>1073.25</ExtendedLineAmount>
            <ItemStatus>Backorder</ItemStatus>
            <ExpectedDate>2022-05-25</ExpectedDate>
        </OrderLine>
    </LineItem>
    <LineItem>
        <OrderLine>
            <UnitPrice>292.410000</UnitPrice>
            <ExtendedLineAmount>584.82</ExtendedLineAmount>
            <ItemStatus>Released</ItemStatus>
            <ExpectedDate>2022-06-29</ExpectedDate>
        </OrderLine>
    </LineItem>

</LineItems>
```

Comment: Please add your XML sample to the question

Comment: The **<Purchase>** tag doesn't get closed in your XML sample. Having **<Purchase>** as the root element is inconsistent with your code which implies **<Purchase>** is a child of **<OrderHeader>**: `PurchaseOrderNumber = doc.Root.Element("Header").Element("OrderHeader").Element("Purchase").Value`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

I saved your XML as a "e:\temp\alma.xml" file. And intentionally commented out

```
<!--<ExpectedDate>2022-06-29</ExpectedDate>-->
```

A question mark is standard way in the .Net Framework way to handle missing values as nulls:

```
ExpectedDate = e.Element("ExpectedDate")?.Value
```

Commented out `?? "default value"` should match an expected data type.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Purchase>
    <Header>
        <OrderHeader>
            <TradingId>OPIE</TradingId>
        </OrderHeader>
    </Header>
    <LineItems>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <UnitPrice>1073.25</UnitPrice>
                <ExtendedLineAmount>1073.25</ExtendedLineAmount>
                <ItemStatus>Backorder</ItemStatus>
                <ExpectedDate>2022-05-25</ExpectedDate>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <UnitPrice>292.410000</UnitPrice>
                <ExtendedLineAmount>584.82</ExtendedLineAmount>
                <ItemStatus>Released</ItemStatus>
                <!--<ExpectedDate>2022-06-29</ExpectedDate>-->
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
    </LineItems>
</Purchase>
```

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string filePath = @"e:\temp\alma.xml";
    
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
    var col = doc.Descendants("OrderLine")
            .Select(e => new
            {
                UnitPrice = e.Element("UnitPrice").Value,
                ExtendedLineAmount = e.Element("ExtendedLineAmount").Value,
                ItemStatus = e.Element("ItemStatus").Value,
                ExpectedDate = e.Element("ExpectedDate")?.Value // ?? "default Value"
            });
    Console.WriteLine(col);
}
```

**Output**

```
+------------+--------------------+------------+--------------+
| UnitPrice  | ExtendedLineAmount | ItemStatus | ExpectedDate |
+------------+--------------------+------------+--------------+
|    1073.25 |            1073.25 | Backorder  | 2022-05-25   |
| 292.410000 |             584.82 | Released   | null         |
+------------+--------------------+------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is **I am parsing an XML file in C#, how I can make sure the code is not breaking...**

One approach would be to define a `Purchase` class and use `XmlSerializer` to deserialize the XML `source` you show in your post:

**XmlSerializer Declaration**

```
static XmlSerializer xserdes =
    new XmlSerializer(
    typeof(Purchase),
    new XmlRootAttribute("Purchase"));
```

**Deserialize** the XML to an instance of `Purchase`:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source)))
{
    Purchase purchase = (Purchase)xserdes.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

If a break point is added after `purchase` is deserialized, it can be viewed in the Watch window.

[image: watch window]

- The missing value for `ExpectedDate` shows as `null` without throwing an exception.
- Wherever you see `try_get_element` this is just referring to the `namespace`.

**CONDITIONS**

I have defined `Purchase` based on your code sample:

```
public class Purchase
{
    public Header Header { get; set; }
    public LineItems LineItems { get; set; }
}
public class Header
{
    public OrderHeader OrderHeader { get; set; }
}
public class OrderHeader
{
    public string TradingId { get; set; }
}
public class LineItems : List<LineItem>
{ }
public class LineItem 
{ 
    public OrderLine OrderLine { get; set; }
}
public class OrderLine
{
    public string VendorPartNumber { get; set; }
    public string UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public string ExtendedLineAmount { get; set; }
    public string ItemStatus { get; set; }
    public string ExpectedDate { get; set; }
}
```

The `source` follows your Xml sample as closely as possible (the value tag for the 2nd `ExpectedDate` has been removed as your post indicates):

```
const string source =
@"<Purchase>
    <Header>
        <OrderHeader>
            <TradingId>OPIE</TradingId>
        </OrderHeader>
    </Header>
    <LineItems>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <VendorPartNumber>1</VendorPartNumber>
                <UnitPrice>1073.25</UnitPrice>
                <ExtendedLineAmount>1073.25</ExtendedLineAmount>
                <ItemStatus>Backorder</ItemStatus>
                <ExpectedDate>2022-05-25</ExpectedDate>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <OrderLine>
                <VendorPartNumber>2</VendorPartNumber>
                <UnitPrice>292.410000</UnitPrice>
                <ExtendedLineAmount>584.82</ExtendedLineAmount>
                <ItemStatus>Released</ItemStatus>
            </OrderLine>
        </LineItem>
    </LineItems>
</Purchase>";
```